# Office365 Graph API - Mark as Read/Unread not updating lastModifiedDateTime

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

When emails are marked as read/unread it doesn't seem to update the lastModifiedDateTime attribute, so I'm not sure how my application can pull down this change. I had been planning to use a query with a filter on lastModifiedDateTime to check for all actions/changes to emails.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Perform this query in Graph Explorer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime desc
```

2) Mark an email as read or unread in Outlook OWA

3) Perform the above query again, and notice that the email you marked as read/unread has not jumped to the top of the list

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking read/unread has historically not modified the message itself. Are you trying to track changes? If so, take a look at [message sync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Synchronizemessagespreview) which is in preview. It will send a change event if you mark read/unread.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that. Just to confirm - do you mean that lastModifiedDateTime does not get updated by design and that this is not a bug?